# How to query on another query result?

Tags: sql

I have a problem as I am not so strong on queries.

I have a query with consists of a union of two select queries :

```
   SELECT em.emp_code,  
          em.emp_name,  
          COALESCE(SUM(pe.hours_allotted),0) AS hours,  
          pe.dated 
     FROM employee_master em
LEFT JOIN project_employee pe ON (pe.Emp_code = em.emp_code)
    WHERE (dated >= '2011-03-14'
      AND dated < '2011-03-20' ) 
       OR dated IS NULL 
 GROUP BY em.emp_code 
UNION
  (SELECT em.emp_code,
          em.emp_name,
          '0' AS hours,
          pe.dated
     FROM employee_master em
LEFT JOIN project_employee pe ON (pe.Emp_code = em.emp_code)
    WHERE (dated >= '2011-03-14'
      AND dated < '2011-03-20' ) 
       OR dated IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY em.Emp_code)
ORDER BY emp_name;
```

Now the result sets are returning for example as:

```
ecode  ename    hours 
----------------------
201   Alak basu  10 
201 alak basu    0
```

The first result is from first select statement of the union where hours = 10 
and hours = 0 is from second select statement of union.

What I want is:

```
ecode     ename       hours 
----------------------------
201      alak basu     10
```

Like in the case there should be only one result per ecode. How to group it like summing up the hours on as group by ecode so that it gives me only one result as above?

Comment: Why is your data so broken as to have the same name twice with different capitalization?

Comment: I feel like there's a logic failure here that needs to be addressed. If an employee has a `dated` field within the given time frame, it will match both queries, and be present on both sides of the union. I have a feeling that this is not intended. What exactly is the intended effect of this query?

Comment: @jdmichal actually d intend was we have an attendance based thing in which we have to populate on daily basis who is working how many hours .... now for the time being we needed to know that in date from 14th march to 19th march .. how many people are actually working whoz working hours is more than 6 hours .... (Note : only those employee would be in the project employee who are working on that perticular day..)

Comment: so thts d reason some of the dated field inspite of left join was null.... but apart from that... whose dated field isnt null.. and also they have worked more than 6 hours ... so i had to break the logic into two parts because of which i required d union i may not b able to tell the entire thing properly but thats d actual scenario

Comment: Yes, but if you just let no hours through for an employee (`NULL`), the `COALESCE` will convert it to zero. Since you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`, every employee will be represented, and if they do not have a matching `project_employees` row, their hours will be `NULL`. So, again, the second part of the `UNION` does not do anything. See my answer for an update of what the SQL should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```
select emp_code, min(emp_name) as emp_name, sum(hours)
from (
  <your original query here>
) as e
group by emp_code
order by emp_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the desired result is to sum all hours for a single employee code into a single row, and the second query after the `UNION` will only ever return zero hours, it seems like the best solution here is to get rid of the `UNION`.

EDIT: After further clarification, here's what I think the SQL should probably look like:

```
SELECT em.emp_code,
       em.emp_name,
       COALESCE(pe.hours, 0) AS hours
FROM employee_master em
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT emp_code,
           SUM(hours_allotted) AS hours
    FROM project_employee
    WHERE dated >= '2011-03-14' AND
          dated < '2011-03-20'
    GROUP BY emp_code
    ) pe ON (pe.emp_code = em.emp_code)
ORDER BY em.emp_name;
```

What it's doing:

1. Perform a subquery to filter all `project_employee` entries to the ones within the specified date range. (Note that there is no need for `NULL` or `NOT NULL` checks at all here. Either the date is in range, or it is not.)
2. Sum the hours for each employee code generated in the subquery.
3. Take all employees in the `employee_master` table, and search for matching entries in the filtered, summed `project_employee` subquery result set. (Since it is a `LEFT JOIN`, every employee in the master table will have an entry, even if none of the filtered `project_employee` entries matched.)
4. In the case that there is no match, the `pe.hours` column will be `NULL`, causing the `COALESCE` to revert to its second value of zero.
5. Order results by `emp_name`.

Comment: @jdmichal but the problem is i have two sets with completely diffrent conditions ... one is taking as dated is null and another is taking dated is not null ....so i cant get rid of union either :(

Comment: If they are different conditions, then why is your example giving the same employee twice? Or is that what the question is?

Comment: @jdmichal, +1 Aggreed. The second section does not seem required, and also, in such a situation, a case statement could have been used as well.

Comment: @jdmichal i tried ur query.. but its giving error on mysql.... not sure whats causing it :(

Comment: @Joy I have fixed a couple minor syntax issues. (Extra terminating comma first `SELECT` list and missing semi-colon at the end of the query.) At this point it passes MSSQL syntax checker. I do not have a MySQL instance to test against.

Comment: @jdmichal  ya i fixed it already... thanks again there were small issues ... i fixed it :)